# Function to Detect non-numerical characters not working

Tags: javascript, html, function, slice, html-input

I have this JavaScript function:

```
   function a(elem) {
  b = elem.value;
  c = b.substring(b.length - 1);

  if (c !== '1' && c !== '2' && c !== '3' && c !== '4' && c !== '5' && c !== '6' && c !== '7' && c !== '8' && c !== '9' && c !== '0' && c !== '.') {
    elem.value = b.slice(0, -1);
  }
};
```

The function will be applied to numerical inputs as such:

```
<input type='number' onkeyup='a(this)'/>
```

The  point of the function is to detect if there is a character that is not 0-9 or a period entered into the input, and if there is, it is supposed to set the value of that input to what it was, minus the last character(the non-numeral character).

My problem is that instead of replacing the value of the input with my new string, it simply clears the input. Any idea why? Can you find a fix for it? Any help would be much-appreciated. Thanks!

P.S. regular JavaScript answers only, please. No jQuery, if you don't mind.

## Note

This may have something to do with the type of the input being a numerical input. Unfortunately, that needs to stay the same unless absolutely necessary.

## EDIT #2

I have narrowed it down to fact that the problem is somehow caused by input type=number. This is strange, because setting the value of the input like this

```
document.getElementById('myinput').value='68';
```

works fine

Comment: All those `&&` could be replaced with a simple regexp check.

Comment: not familiar with regex. sorry. But that's not why I asked the question. I can live with a long conditional.

Comment: Characters can be added anywhere in the string, not just the end, so making the assumption that only the last character can be incorrect isn't sensible.

Comment: it is, because each time a key is released, it checks the character

Comment: Just explanation - OP's code works perfectly on input type='text', question is why on input type='number'  all characters are removed....

Comment: You could shorten it to `if ((c < '0' || C >'9') && c !== '.')`.

Comment: `because each time a key is released, it checks the character` - it checks the last (i.e. rightmost) character in the input box, not necessarily the last character entered at the current caret position

Comment: @Leshy—it just checks the last character in the value, it doesn't check the actual character added. Type 0, then move the cursor to before the 0 and type A. This would be much simpler using a regular expression.

Comment: @RobG, ok that's right, but, moving of cursor aside... do you have idea why on input type=text script works (per OP's intention) and on input type=number it doesn't work as intended?

Comment: @Leshy, you can simplify your code, and also, remove non-digit chars even if user tries to 'cheat' (to move cursor) on this way: http://jsfiddle.net/98hnqfyj/ .... BUT, this remains mystery: http://jsfiddle.net/98hnqfyj/1/

Comment: using `developer tools` (has anyone here heard of them?) you can see that the input .value becomes empty as soon as validate.valid is false - at least in firefox. chrome doesn't even need any javascript to reject non-numeric input - even pasting "123xxx123" simply ignores the non numeric characters - allowed are `-` `0-9` `.` and `e`

Comment: You could also do `if ( "0123456789.".indexOf(c) === -1 ) {...}`.

Comment: @JaromandaX, "has anyone here heard of them?" - never heard about it... Does it exists in Firefox? :) Joke aside, how to check, hm... 'internal properties™', like validity, of elements (in firefox)? I really don't know...

Comment: I just want to point out that your approach will break if the end user presses multiple invalid keys at the same time.  You should instead filter the entire `elem.value` on every `keyup`.

Comment: @Barmar Your edit of this question is [under discussion on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305808/user-edited-my-question-to-fit-his-answer).

Answer (score 2):

You're removing the last character twice. First with

```
b = b.substring(0, b.length - 1);
```

and again with:

```
elem.value = b.slice(0, -1);
```

Do one or the other, but not both.

```js
function a(elem) {
  b = elem.value;
  c = b.substring(b.length - 1);

  if (c !== '1' && c !== '2' && c !== '3' && c !== '4' && c !== '5' && c !== '6' && c !== '7' && c !== '8' && c !== '9' && c !== '0' && c !== '.') {
    elem.value = b.slice(0, -1);
  }
};
```

```html
<input type='text' onkeyup='a(this)'/>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with input type=number. Is there any way to make it do so?

Comment: If you use `number` type, the browser won't allow you to type anything other than numbers, so you don't need to use Javascript.

Comment: @Leshy I changed the code to match the question. With number type, I couldn't type a letter in the first place, so it never executed the JS that removes that character.

Comment: @Barmar, that's correct, but for Chrome - in Firefox, user actually can type anything.

Comment: @Barmar what browser are you using? Firefox and IE (the two browsers I am targeting because these are what businesses use) allow letter to be typed into a number input

Comment: I'm using Chrome. The only letter it allows is `e` because it's part of scientific notation (e.g. `1e3` meaning `1000`).

Answer (score 0):

Your function is almost perfect. 
Two problems though:

1. while taking last character of "b" into "c" check if the length of
   b is greater than 1. Otherwise you are just killing every character
   that is being entered.
2. Do not slice the last character, substring is already doing it in
   the if loop, you are cutting 2 characters for every one character
   added. Have only substring and assign "b" back to the element.

You will be all set.

Comment: Third problem, when <input `type='number'` and you entere non numeric in Firefox at least, the input elements .value == ''

Comment: I was just talking about the function. Of course the input should be text

Comment: `of course the input should be text` ... only because browsers are stupid. it make way more sense for the input to be number for a numeric input :p

Comment: Agree, in which case a function like this is not necessary :)

Comment: @stk—some would say that this isn't necessary anyway and that such functionality is just an annoyance. The OP's code isn't anywhere near perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is obvious that keeping of `input type=number` causes cross-browser headache, in this case, i suggest using of `text` type, and this code:

```
function a(elem){
  b=elem.value;

elem.value=b.replace(/[^0-9.]+/,'');

};
```

This should replace ALL unwanted characters, wherever user try to type it, if cursor is moved, if user press and holds key (not sure about `paste`, though:))...

So, check the whole string, rather than last character, and replace everything except digits and dots...

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/98hnqfyj/2/

Comment: This solution accepts "123.45.67" as valid numerical input,  and rejects negative numbers.  Totally agree on checking entire input rather than one character at a time.  You have to take care of +,-, . , e and make sure they only occur once, and in the right location, which makes it more than a bit of a pain.

Comment: Yes... but op wants to limit input just to dots and digits, as I remember...so, he needs little limited version of number input type... regarding dot... yep the place must be checked too... pain, in any case :)

Comment: All this extra checking would probably be easier to manage during validation at submission time, rather than on a per-character basis.

Answer (score -1):

When you set the input type to "number", you don't need to do any checks for digits - the input box takes care of that and will ignore non-digit characters.  The problem is that when you type an additional "." when you've already got a floating point number, the behavior of the input element is to clear out the entire input and not make it available in `elem.value` and set `elem.valueAsNumber` to `NaN`.  That is, you have no way to retrieve the rest of what's been typed previously - at least I can't find anything after 20 minutes of hacking in Chrome console and checking MDN.

If you're willing to make the box of type "text", then the following will work and is reasonably clean. Otherwise, no idea how to solve this for you.

```
function a(elem){
  var b = elem.value;
  if (Number.isNaN(+elem.value) ) {
    elem.value=b.substring(0,b.length-1);
  }

};
```

Comment: @JaromandaX—I think the unspoken part is "If the browser supports input type number, then…".

Comment: chrome and firefox support input type number. Chrome works ok, firefox works like a pig ...

Comment: the code I posted doesn't like `.` or `e` - which is why I removed a bad answer

Comment: Nope, the code you posted didn't like floating point numbers on any browser.  It was flat broken.